# How to get data after the first save in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this application:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);
  const [car, setCar] = useState({
    name: "",
    color: ""
  });
  const handleChange = e => {
    setCar({
      ...car,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  const addCar = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCars([...cars, car]);
    setCar({
      car: "",
      color: ""
    });
    console.log(cars);
  };

  return (
    <div className="car">
      <form onSubmit={addCar}>
        <input
          value={car.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="name"
          placeholder="add car name"
        />
        <input
          value={car.color}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="color"
          placeholder="add car color"
        />
        <button type="submit">Add a car</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The issue appears when i want to save data clicking on `save` button. To get the data in `console.log(cars);`, i have to click twice.

Why this is happening and how to solve this?
demo:https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-fog-jstgi?file=/src/App.js:436-454

Answer (score 0):

Your data saves properly, but becuase of useState, when you try to console the updated state you get the last result without updating. You can change your code to work properly

```
  const addCar = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCars([...cars, car]);
    setCar({
      car: "",
      color: ""
    });
    console.log([...cars, car]);
  };
```

Comment: why, now, if i type in inputs, this text: console.log("render"); is rendering every time, and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use setState() it doesn't always happen immediately its an asynchronous call, meaning that the "cars" state will not be changed right after that 'setState' line, but no need to worry the state is changing,

to confirm that your state is changing you can use "useEffect" hook just to check the new value, and then remove it later

```
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log(cars);
   }),[cars]);
```

You will notice that your cars will be logged after you click, its just that you can't rely on "setState" new value right after you call it.

You can remove the "useEffect" hook when you see that the state is changing properly as its no longer necessary.

Comment: why, now, if i type in inputs, this text: `console.log("render");` is rendering every time, and how to avoid this?

Comment: Its because you are changing the state, and changing the state triggers a rerender, which is totally normal if its not causing any logical errors you can let it be, its how React handle state changes